# how to return an reference to an 'empty' object

Tags: c++, reference, return

The problem I tried to tackle today is the one where you want to return a reference, but you actually can't because in some specific case you return something 'empty'. Just to clarify, something like this:

```
std::array<std::string, 5> cStrings /* do something to init */

const std::string& get_my_string(/* args */) {
    if(i_know_what_to_return()) {
        /* 
         * returning happily something in 
         * cStrings if I know what
         */
    } else {
        /* oeps... i need to return something, I don't have :-( */

        return std::string(); // DON'T TRY THIS AT HOME!
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is not a generic approach to avoid the creation of empty objects all over the place, or, even worse, start returning copies of the objects. So I was wondering if I could not create some sort of template class that allows me to tell the compiler to manage this for me. This was my approach (although its only one of many, all with a small variation in the template declaration since this produces an error)

```
template<typename T, decltype(T) V>
struct empty_reference {
    using type = T;
    static const T static_object_;
    operator T&() const {
        return static_object_;
    }
};

template<typename T, decltype(T) V>
const typename empty_reference<T, V>::type
    empty_reference<T, V>::static_object_ = V;
```

unfortunately, this does not work (I get an error on 'decltype(T) V' saying 'decltype expects an expression not a type'), but I guess this is mainly because I am missing something in the template declaration.
In the end I am hoping to use this class by returning

```
return empty_reference<std::string, std::string()>();
```

So I have three questions here;

1. could this be possible
2. how do I make this work, what should I turn 'decltype(T) V' into to tell the compiler that V should be of type T while still being evaluated during compilation?
3. and is this a good approach or is there an easier/better solution to this problem?

Comment: You are looking for `std::optional` (C++17) or boost.optional.

Comment: "Nullable reference" sounds a lot like "pointer"?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I was going to suggest `optional`, but can it contain a reference?

Comment: One question per question please

Comment: @BoBTFish Double checked, they can.

Comment: @BaummitAugen @BoBTFish It won't be allowed in C++17. See [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional#syn-1) (working draft) - _A program that necessitates the instantiation of template optional for a reference type [...] is ill-formed_. You can still use `std::reference_wrapper` with it.

Comment: @skypjack Ok, thanks for the reference. cppr may need some correction I guess, based my wrong assertion above on it.

Comment: both the optional as the pointer needs checking, I meant empty like empty constructor

Comment: @user2546926 I added two examples where you don't have to check the returned value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly the same, but you can get your string as a function parameter instead of as a return value and rely on the fact that temporaries bind to const references.
As an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct S {
    template<typename F>
    void get(bool b, F &&f) {
        std::forward<F>(f)(b ? s : "");
    }

    std::string s{"foo"};
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.get(true, [](const auto &str) { std::cout << str << std::endl; });
    s.get(false, [](const auto &str) { std::cout << str << std::endl; });
}
```

This can be a valid alternative if libraries like Boost are not already part of your project and you don't want to include them.

---

Otherwise, as others have mentioned, you can pick up an upcoming utility called `std::optional` and combine it with `std::reference_wrapper` as it follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/optional>
#include <functional>

struct S {
    std::experimental::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>> get(bool b) {
        return b ? std::ref(s) : std::experimental::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>>{};
    }

    std::string s{"foo"};
};

int main() {
    S s;

    auto opt1 = s.get(true);
    std::cout << (opt1 ? opt1->get() : "-") << std::endl;

    auto opt2 = s.get(false);
    std::cout << (opt2 ? opt2->get() : "-") << std::endl;
}
```

Pretty ugly indeed. Note that a `std::optional` should be verified through its `operator bool` or the member method `has_value` to be sure that it contains a value.

Unfortunately you cannot use directly a `std::reference_wrapper` as return value, for it cannot be (let me say) _empty). In other terms, if you want to construct such an object, you must pass a valid reference to its constructor.

---

Another approach would be by using a template class like the following one:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct defval {
    static const std::decay_t<T> value;
};

template<typename T>
const std::decay_t<T> defval<T>::value = T{};

struct S {  
    const std::string & get(bool b) {
        return b ? str : defval<std::string>::value;
    }

    std::string str{"foo"};
};

int main() {
    S s;
    std::cout << s.get(true) << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.get(false) << std::endl;
}
```

Note that you must specialize it for those types that are not default constructible.

Comment: well, the whole idea of creating the template 'class empty_ref' was to tell the compiler to create a valid object what can be used to return the reference. The string object was only an example to explain the problem, because I run into this not only for string, but also for user defined types...

Comment: @user2546926 The reverted approach that accepts a function solves the issue with every type.

Comment: @user2546926 Added another approach based on a template class that introduces a default value to be used when needed.

Comment: didn't see you last approach, that looks like it is doing indeed where I was aiming for, and a lot smaller, didn't realize. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

References must be bound to an object. So you can't return a reference in your case. Your options are:

1. Return a (non-owning) pointer.
2. Return something like `boost::optional`, which can hold a reference (unlike the soon to be added `std::optional`).

Comment: `std::optional` cannot hold a reference, see [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional#syn-1) (working draft) - _A program that necessitates the instantiation of template optional for a reference type [...] is ill-formed_.

Comment: @skypjack, that's a shame.

Comment: It could be, but you shouldn't blame me for that!! :-)

Comment: @skypjack, I don't shoot the messenger for bad news :)

Comment: The optional does come close to what I was aiming for, however, like the pointer approach, it enforces the 'client' to look whether the value exisits. My aim here was to construct something that would return something that is 'empty' in the sense of an empty constructor like string(), int() or ...

Answer (score -1):

So at some point I figured it out, at least I guess.

```
template<typename T>
struct empty_reference {
    using type = T;
    static const type static_object_;
    operator const type&() {
        return static_object_;
    }
};

template<typename T>
const typename empty_reference<T>::type
    empty_reference<T>::static_object_ = {};
```

The concept is that the compiler will 'generate' one static 'static_object_' member for all types you use it for. Therefore, for any type you used the empty_reference for, a static object is generated in your application and returned when they are requested (i.e. if you return `empty_reference<int>` in two different files, a reference to the same int value will be returned).

The key was to remove the '`decltype(T) V`' completely and use the universal initialization (i.e. `{}`) to make sure that any 'empty' constructor is called to initialize the object.

The downside is the reference needs to be constant (otherwise you can edit your 'empty reference') and the type is required to be constructable using an empty constructor.

So I guess the only question remaining is whether it is a good idea (I am not going to just my own ideas). Happy to receive any other suggestions/feedback :-)